# What is this HTML page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new at frontend. I have a html page that I meed to analized to do my project and I don't undrstand it.
Is it Bootstrap?
What are those tags in {}?
Where could I learn about it?
Sorry for my english.
Thank You.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="informacja-o-naprawie">
                    <div id="repair-progres">
                        <div id="repair-progres-graph" style="display: inline-table;">{sqldivmenu}job-status-menu{/sqldivmenu}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{msgdlg}dlg_info{/msgdlg}
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="row">{dbcardcontrol colcount=2 titlewidth=200 sqlextprops=job_fieldsprops}qrs_job{/dbcardcontrol}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="fright">
                <div class="dtable">
                    <div class="drow">
                        <div class="dcell">{artmenu sqlextprops=repair_printouts css=partmenustatitem}repair_printouts{/artmenu}</div>
                        <div class="dcell">{artmenu errctr=err_dlg sqlextprops=repair_adv}repair_adv{/artmenu}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">{jqacc HideTabs=job_hidetabs}qrs_job{/jqacc}</div></div>

{ModalWithPostBack htmlid=36889 sqlload=jobchangedeviceinfo_visible}qrs_repair_deviceinfopanel{/ModalWithPostBack}

{ModalWithPostBack htmlid=36891 sqlload=jobsetdeliverynote_visible}qrs_repair_deliverynotepanel{/ModalWithPostBack}
{ModalWithPostBack htmlid=37699 sqlload=qrs_jobcreateorderandbook_visible}CreateOrderAndBook{/ModalWithPostBack}
{ModalWithPostBack htmlid=38737}editendcustomer{/ModalWithPostBack}
```

Comment: It's html + some bootstrap classes but the `{}` stuff seem like some custom elements that use sql queries  and which are rendered as html elements. Not familiar with them. Question. What is the file extension ? How is this project rendered ? What kind of assignment is this ? What do you mean by ' analyze ' ?

Comment: Thank You for your willingness to help. I have this code not from any extended file, but from a text printout. I have backend education, but I got my first IT job at frontend company. My supervisor showed me this printout and said I needed to find the stored procedures for the controls (the controls on the HTML page). I know how to write scripts in tsql and a bit of HTML and CSS, but I do not understand a word of this. Where are thouse controls here?
We use .NET platform in work.

Comment: From my point of view, this is not just frontend. The controls i presume are `dbcardcontrol ` stuff but have no idea ( from the code and info you shared ) where are the procedures for them. I can only presume they are in the backend in .NET. Which is why i say this is not just frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed bootstrap, you can see that by the insane amount of div tags and especially the class names like col-xs-10 and col-xs-12 and row.

The things in the {} are likely placeholders thats part of some templating engine, the engine will likely remove the things in the {} and replace it with data which could be dynamicly updated for example:

```
<div>hello mr {name}</div>
```

I do not reconise this template engine syntax, if someone knows it, please let me know or edit this answer.